# Open specific viewController in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm using a `tableView` like the iPhone's note application.
I can add/delete note (`cells`).

I'm facing a little issue when I delete a note.

Here's my code:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)



    switch (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row {
    case 0:




        let Liste1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "liste1") as UIViewController
        self.present(Liste1, animated: false, completion: nil)

    case 1:
        let Liste2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "liste2") as UIViewController
        self.present(Liste2, animated: false, completion: nil)

    case 2:
        let Liste3 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "liste3") as UIViewController
        self.present(Liste3, animated: false, completion: nil)



    default:
        break 

    }
```

As you can see, each `indexPath.row` can open a counted `ViewController`.
If I have 3 notes and I delete the 2nd, the 3rd will open the 2nd `viewController`. Tell me if you don't understand..
I know the problem , I don't know if there are some solutions to open specific `viewController` .

I want Cells is linked to a `viewController`, not by the indexPath..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation here is wrong. How it should be is that a ViewController (say named DetailsViewController) should be pushed whenever the user selects a cell. Only the text associated text/note should change. The correct note should be fetched from an array of all the notes (with index being the indexPath.row of the selected cell) and then pass is to DetailsViewController while presenting it.

**Deleting a note:**
When the user deletes a note, just delete the not from this array of all notes.